React Native Android app shows a white screen when debugging
Problem:
Whenever I try to debug my React Native Android app, I encounter a white empty screen. This issue occurs after I open the developer menu and select the "Debug" option. The Chrome debugger opens, and my app crashes, leading to the white screen. I cannot close the debugger mode without removing the app data from the emulator.
Steps to Reproduce:
Launch the React Native app on an Android emulator.
Open the developer menu by shaking the device or using Ctrl + M.
Select "Debug" from the menu.
The Chrome debugger opens.
The app crashes and shows a white screen.
To recover, I have to remove the app data from the emulator.
What I've Tried:
Restarting the emulator and my development machine.
Clearing the app data and cache from the emulator.
Reinstalling the React Native app.
Checking for any error messages in the terminal and Chrome console.
Additional Information:
React Native version: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
Emulator: Android Studio AVD (Pixel 7a API 31)
Operating System: Windows 10
Expected Behavior:
The app should run normally and allow me to debug using Chrome without crashing and displaying a white screen.
Actual Behavior:
The app crashes and shows a white screen when I try to debug using Chrome.

Which react native version are you using ?

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.69.12
